# Can I upload .c or .cpp file using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to upload a .c file. I am using CodeIgniter. The code I am using is working for .pdf but whenever I try to upload a .c file it shows "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.".

My code is given below:

```
$config = array
(
    'upload_path' => './solutions',
    'allowed_types' => 'c',
    'file_name' => $file_name,
    'file_size' => 1000,
    'remove_spaces' => 'true'
);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

When I write pdf in allowed types, it works, but not in the case of C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In allowed_types you need to have MIME types.

For a c source file that would be "text/plain", since there is no "c" MIME type.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: also take a look at config/mimes.php :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have successfully uploaded a c file. :) :) :D